# If $(|x_n|)_n$ and $(|y_n|)_n$ are increasing, is $(|x_n+y_n|)_n$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ be two sequences of complex numbers such that

> - $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ are bounded.
> - $(|x_n|)_n$ and $(|y_n|)_n$ are increasing.
>
> Is $(|x_n+y_n|)_n$ increasing? If not, I hope to find a counter-example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $x_n=1-1/n$ and $y_n = -(1-2/n)$.